# CodeIgniter: Form Validation and displaying errors

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm passing my validation errors to the next redirect using `set_flashdata`, however when I use this method I loose the data the user has inputted in the form. Is my approach incorrect here?

```
if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('errors', validation_errors());        
    redirect($this->input->post('redirect'));
}
else {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dosc says [this](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#the-controller). Or in example:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('Not your cup of tea.');

class Auth extends CI_Controller
{
    public function login()
    {
        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            //$this->session->set_flashdata('errors', validation_errors()); #errors will be available without flashdata as well       
            //redirect($this->input->post('redirect')); #just load view again
            $this->load->view('view_where_form_with_action_auth_login_is')
        }
        else
        {
            // do stuff
            redirect('whereever', 'location')
        }
    }
}
```